# Find the nearest value to the given one in set

Tags: python, set, min

I am trying to find the closest number to 5 in set b. This is my code.

```
b={1,2,45,65,3,2,8}
one=5
a=set()
for x in b:
  c=abs(x-one)  
  a.add(c)
print(min(a))
```

Comment: Why should the minimum of the set be 3? When `x` is 3, you subtract 5, giving `-2`, which you then take the absolute value of, giving you `2`, which you then add to the set `a`, making it the smallest value

Comment: What influences the choice of using a set instead of a list for an operation like this one?

Comment: @SeyiDaniel Why list? And with the straightforward solution, it wouldn't even matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `key` argument to `min` to achieve this:

```
b = {1,2,45,65,3,2,8}
target = 5 
result = min(b, key=lambda x: abs(x - target))
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this looks intersting. So b is the element in b where abs(x-target) is the minimum? Is  this a way to refere to an elemnt in set. Because sets do not have index number??

Comment: `result` is the element in the set `b` such that `abs(result - target)` is smaller than or equal to every other element in `b`. I don't know what you mean by "a way to refer to an element in a set".

Comment: I mean sets do not support indexing.

Comment: That's right. They do support testing for membership (with `elem in some_set`) and iteration (so they can be used for `for` loops, or as arguments for functions like `min` that take iterables) but not indexing.

Comment: @JasmijnThe code  gives me zero for b = {0,-2}
target = -1 ,,,is there a way to check  If 2 numbers are at the same distance, I could  choose the smallest one; in this case get -2 instead?

Comment: Nevermind, found the solution,,,min(sorted(values), key=lambda value: abs(one - value))

Comment: Another way of doing that without sorting them would be `min(values, key=lambda value: (abs(one - value), value))`, taking advantage of the ordering of tuples.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're adding the difference between the reference value and the values in the set, so 5-3 = 2. I'd suggest an even better improvement, don't use set at all since they are very inefficient compared to just using variables like shown:

```
b={1,2,45,65,3,2,8}
one=5

nearest = None
smallest_gap = None
for x in b:
    nearest = x
    smallest_gap = abs(one - x)
    break

for x in b:
  if abs(one - x)<smallest_gap:
    smallest_gap = abs(one - x)
    nearest = x
print(nearest)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you were to find the closest element to 5 using a list, here's how you can go about it:

```
b={1,2,45,65,3,2,8}
b = list(b)
one=5
a=[]
for x in b:
  c=abs(x-one)  
  a.append(c)
print(b[a.index(min(a))])
```